# How do I get a Simperium API Key for accessing my own SimpleNote data

Tags: http, simperium

I signed up for a Simperium account. And I created a new "App" in the Simperium Dashboard. This app's page has an API admin key and an app ID.

But can I use those credentials when accessing my SimpleNote data through the API ?

Does SimpleNote have its own universal App ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We aren't issuing new Simperium API keys for Simplenote anymore. Simplenote is a regular app on Simperium though so it has a normal app-id etc. We'll soon add a feature to the Simplenote web app where users can request an API token. This will be a regular Simperium token, which, paired with the Simplenote appid, you can make requests. We'll update this page: http://simplenote.com/developers/ with more info soon.

Comment: .@ecksor Any updates on this yet? It's three years now.

Comment: Hope there will be a regular Simperium Token.